# Связать модели разных приложений

Tags: python, django

Как и при добавлении объекта модели первого приложения, добавить его в качестве другой модели во второе приложение со свойствами первого объекта?

```
# firstApp.models
class itemInShop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, 
                       max_length=100,editable=False)
    descr = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=5000)
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=5000)
    propertiesManufacturer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    propertiesType = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    propertiesPrice = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    propertiesPower = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    propertiesAmount = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Пример модели второго приложения. Является ли это возможным?

```
class Pech(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=100, 
                                choices=CHOICES_PECHI_MANUFACTURER, 
                                blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=100, 
                        choices=CHOICES_PECHI_TYPE)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    power = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю верный ли это способ, но я сделал бы так.

Если у вас 2 приложения, то первое, что нам надо сделать: придумать как они будет взаимодейстовать, возможно через обычный http или что-нибудь посерьезнее, типа RabbitMQ или Redis, выбор будет зависеть от того, как часто будут создаваться такие модели(или как часто приложениям надо будет взаимодействовать), в вашем случае думаю обычного http хватит. Т.е 1 приложение просто будет посылать обычный POST запрос, а второе принимать, извлекать данные и создавать модель(используйте [form models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) для большей эффективности и чистоты кода).

2 вопрос, когда нужно посылать такой запрос, ответ: когда создается модель в 1 приложении, для этого используйте [обработчик сигнала post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/). И последнее надо позаботиться о безопасности http соединения, между приложениями, для этого используйте куки от запроса на 1 приложение для запроса на 2ое, если приложения используют одну и туже бд для сессий, то на втором сразу можно будет определить, кто изначально сделал запрос и тем самым обезопасить себя.